# What does the reference vector mean when it comes to LQG/LQR controllers?

Tags: dynamical-systems, matlab, control-theory, optimal-control, kalman-filter

What does the reference vector $r(t)$ mean when it comes to LQG/LQR controllers? Because if I set $r(t) = 0$, then my controller will place the states at the equilibrium point. And if i changes my reference to $r(t) = 5$, the equilibrium point will move up or down.

But what does the reference vector $r(t)$ mean? Do I changes the eigenvalues of the system? Reference $r(t) = 5$ is just a number without any unit.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $\hat{x}(t)$ converges to $x(t)$ in steady state, the system is asymptotically stable (so $A-L\,C$ and $A-B\,K$ are Hurwitz) and $r(t)$ is periodic with period $T$, and thus can be written as a Fourier series

$$
r(t) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n\,e^{\frac{2\,\pi\,i\,n\,t}{T}},
$$

with $c_n$ a complex valued vector with the same dimensions as $u$.

Under these assumptions when the transient of the system has died out the response of the system can be expressed as

$$
x(t) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \left(\frac{2\,\pi\,i\,n}{T}\,I - A + B\,K\right)^{-1} B\,c_n\,e^{\frac{2\,\pi\,i\,n\,t}{T}}.
$$

For example when it is just a constant $r(t)=c_0$ then in steady state $x(t)=(B\,K-A)^{-1} B\,c_0$ and $y(t) = C\,(B\,K-A)^{-1} B\,c_0$. It can be noted that $A-B\,K$ is assumed to be Hurwitz, so does not have eigenvalues at zero and therefore that inverse should exist.

The input $r(t)$ can be seen as feedforward. So for example if you have some constant reference $y_r(t)$ for the output you would like to track, then you could scale this reference to get the feedforward $r(t) = \left(C\,(B\,K-A)^{-1} B\right)^{-1} y_r(t)$. If that matrix is not square or invertable, then you could use the [right (pseudo) inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_element#Matrices).

Comment: Thank you for the teoretical answer. So if I can compute which $r$ gives me $y$ ?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson The existence of a $r(t)$ which would result in perfect tracking of $y_r(t)$ would depend on the system and $y_r(t)$. For example if your system is a mass-spring-damper system with outputs the full state so both position and velocity and you have a $y_r(t)$ such that both the position and velocity are a non-zero constant, then it would be physically impossible to track this.

Comment: Ok. Then I know that focusing on $r$ to control $y$ is not worth at all.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson Using feedforward in general can give huge performance improvements. So it is not only applicable in LQG. Also with my previous comment I tried to say that you also need to take the reference you choose into consideration.

Comment: What is "feedforward"? You mean LQI?

Comment: OK! Now I understand what you're saying. If I implement an integrator inside a LQR (or LQG), the $y$ can easily be tracking $r$ then.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson feedforward is often implemented [as follows](http://computationalnonlinear.asmedigitalcollection.asme.org/data/journals/jcnddm/927599/cnd_009_01_011014_f001.png). In this case the block diagram is slightly different. But in general it does hold that feedback is closed-loop, while feedforward is open-loop. So as long as the feedforward filter is stable, then the system stability will not change. An ideal feedforward filter would be equal to the inverse of the system. However this is often not causal, but can often still be done if $y_r(t)$ is a number of times differentiable.

Comment: Okey. But I don't think that feedforward fit's my project. It's seems difficult. My goal is quite robust and quite optimal MIMO systems. In this case, I think I will use a LQG/LTR with intergral action. I created a new question about integral action with LQ. I have looked at H2 and Hinf controllers, but they are too theoretical.